# Textbox renders differently on IE and Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, knockout.js

My textbox renders very differently on IE and Chrome

IE

[image]

Chrome

[image]

You can see that width of textbox is small in IE.

My html is defined as

```
 <input id="Name" data-bind ="value:Name" style="width: 210px"/>
```

I tried downloading normalize.css and included at top of my scripts , but still it renders incorrectly on different browsers.

I am sure there would be more input required, so do let me know what you guys need to resolve my issue.

These are the scripts i am using

```
<link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Myfolder/External/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<link href="../Myfolder/External/jQuery UI/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="../Myfolder/External/jQuery UI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>

<link href="../Myfolder/Styling/common.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="../Myfolder/External/Knockout/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>

<script src="../Myfolder/External/JSON/json2.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Myfolder/External/Knockout/Plugins/koExternalTemplateEngine_all.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Myfolder/External/Knockout/Plugins/knockout.validation.js"></script>

<script src="../Myfolder/External/Knockout/Plugins/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<link href="../Myfolder/External/Kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Myfolder/External/Kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Myfolder/External/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Myfolder/External/Bootstrap/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="../Myfolder/External/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="../Myfolder/External/Kendo/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="../NewUI2013/AgrOD/external/amplify/amplify.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Myfolder/External/Knockout/Plugins/knockout-kendo.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Myfolder/External/Knockout/knockout.dirtyFlag.js"></script>
<script src="../Myfolder/Custom/customKO.js"></script>
<script src="../Myfolder/Custom/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: try setting a height to the text-box like 25px.

Comment: You have a lot of css imports there, which will all take precedence over each other in the order in which you import them. The `style` element in your html will then take precedence over your external style sheets. This will be a CSS problem so you need to explain why you're using all those different CSS files.

Comment: If the HTML for your input is from your actual code you are missing the type attribute `type="text"`. Often times modern css frameworks will target inputs by this type `input[type=text] { /** css... **/ }`.

Comment: @Mike i used type = text but didnt helped

Comment: @Aneesh it did helped setting height to 25px. now its exact display on both browser. so do i need to add this height attribute in css?

Comment: define font, border and padding styles and it will be almost same in both browsers. PS and height also

Comment: @cms_mgr You say "The style element in your html will then take precedence over your external style sheets." but that's only true if the `<style>` element is below the `<link>`s. Normally, precedence is top to bottom: a stylesheet that comes later overrides earlier ones, no matter if it's a `<link>` or a `<style>`.

Comment: @MrLister You are of course correct. I was assuming a 'typical' order in the page without knowing. I'd update the comment if I could :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `height:25px` or any other value should solve the issue. The problem most likely that since you used so many css files of external source, the browser maybe misinterpreting some of them.

Comment: I don't think the browser *can* 'misinterpret' the style-sheets, the user/developer *can* put them in the wrong place, or the wrong order, though.

Comment: Maybe not misinterpret in the way I think but they do sometimes. IE used to do percentage rounding off differently that webkit browsers. IE used to have an issue where the min height of an element could never be less than the font height while other browsers support it. I just guessed this could be the issue as its not possible to go through each of those css files he has included.

Comment: @Aneesh i accepted your answer but i dont think its any issue with style sheets.